# Unable to install or run Octave in a Windows docker container

Tags: windows, docker, octave, chocolatey

I'm trying to create a Windows docker container image with [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (CLI) installed.
I started off with a Dockerfile installing Octave via chocolatey:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809

# Install chocolatey
RUN ["powershell", "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"]

# Install Octave
RUN ["powershell", "choco install --yes octave"]
```

Unfortunately the Octave install times out after 2700 seconds, while on my local machine this takes less than 10 minutes.

```
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\octave.install\5.1.0\octave-5.1.0-w64-installer.exe (286.41 MB).
Download of octave-5.1.0-w64-installer.exe (286.41 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing octave.install...
Chocolatey timed out waiting for the command to finish. The timeout 
 specified (or the default value) was '2700' seconds. Perhaps try a 
 higher `--execution-timeout`? See `choco -h` for details.
The install of octave.install was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\octave.install\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

In my second trial I ran a Windows servercore container, copied the Octave installer binary into there and tried to run it, however the start call unfortunately immediately returns with error code `-1073741515`.

My third trial was downloading the portable Octave version and copy it into a running Windows servercore container, copy the portable Octave and run it. Unfortunately when calling `octave-cli.exe` the call again returns immediately with error code `-1073741515`.

I then checked with dependency walker, on my local machine, which dependencies the `octave-cli` has, it seemed to depend on `adoptopenjdk\jdk-14.0.1.7`. In my last trial I installed this dependency in the Windows servercore container via `choco install adoptopenjdk`, this however resulted in the same error code.

I'm curious whether anybody did succeed in installing or running Octave into a Windows docker container?
Or does anyone have any hints for me to proceed?